# How do I duplicate a &[u8] slice?

Tags: rust, borrowing

How do I copy the contents of a `&[u8]` slice?

I'm trying to write a function that takes a buffer as input and XOR's
each byte with the given key and returns the final result.

I don't want it to mangle the input buffer.

```
pub fn xor_buffer(buffer_in: &[u8], key: char) -> &[u8] {

    let mut buffer_out = buffer_in.clone();

    for byte in &mut buffer_out[..] {
        *byte ^= key as u8;
    }

    buffer_out
}
```

This code generates the following compile time error:

```
src/test.rs:29:22: 29:32 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*buffer_out` as mutable
src/test.rs:29     for byte in &mut buffer_out[..] {
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I know I have to be doing something wrong.

Any help would be apprecieated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, you can't `clone` a `[T]` (irrespective of `T`).  Line 3 is not cloning the buffer, *it's cloning the pointer to it*.  If you change the binding to

```
let mut buffer_out: &[u8] = buffer_in.clone();
```

you get the same error.  If you want an independent copy of a slice, you need to turn it into a `Vec` or some other owned container type; that can be done by using `buffer_in.to_owned()` (which generically goes from a borrowed kind of thing to the owned equivalent).

Secondly, you *cannot* return a borrow to something you created in a function.  You can't.  No, really.  No, not even doing that.  Or that.  You can *only* return a borrow (like `&[u8]`) if the return value is *directly* borrowed from one of your arguments.  That is not true here, so the return type *must* be `Vec<u8>` or something else that's owned.

Thirdly, making a copy of the array and *then* mutating it is probably going to be inefficient.  Ideally, you want to do your modifications in as few passes as possible (whilst avoiding even *slower* things like unnecessary allocations).  You can do this using iterators.

Fourth, there's no guarantee `key`'s value actually fits in a `u8`.  You should probably change it to take `key: u8` to make it clear to the caller what the valid range of values is.

So, all together:

```
pub fn xor_buffer(buffer_in: &[u8], key: u8) -> Vec<u8> {
    // Get an iterator of `&u8`s from `buffer_in`.
    buffer_in.iter()
        // Replace each element with the xor'ed value.
        .map(|byte| *byte ^ key)
        // Collect the iterator into an owned collection.
        .collect()
}
```